# Where can I obtain the full DNS zone files for all TLDs?

Tags: internet, dns, lookup, data-dump

Is there a way to get full zone files for all TLDs? I have managed to get my hands on a few (.com, .net, .org), but I'd really like to get some of the country-specific ones for having a play around with, but I have no idea if there is a general procedure to acquire these?

Comment: Where did you get .com, .net, .org from?

Comment: All Verisign needs is some paperwork filled out to get access...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no general procedure because each ccTLD is sovereign and follow the laws of its country. Some allow DNS zone transfers (.AL, .UG, etc), some allow transfers for a fee, with a written contract ([.FR](http://www.afnic.fr/outils/acces-donnees), etc), some deny everything (.DE, as far as I know).

Comment: Is there a list somewhere to find out where I should look to find out the process for individual TLDs? ... I may just have to have a look at what is possible for those that I care most about,

Comment: Not to my knowledge.